# Android NDK - measure time for factorial

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I am new in Android NDK programming but I want to measure time spent with calculation factorial with Android NDK, but it always measures 0 or 1 or 2ms, it's weird.

My Android.mk file looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MY_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)  

LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_PATH)


LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_MODULE    := kru13_ndktest_NDKTestActivity
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c  

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

NDKTest.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_kru13_ndktest_NDKTestActivity_helloLog(
        JNIEnv* env, jobject o, jlong n) {
        jlong faktorial = 1;
        jlong i;
        for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
            faktorial = faktorial * i;
        }
}
```

And NDKTestActivity.java looks like this:

```
package kru13.ndktest;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NDKTestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

public native static void helloLog(long n); 
Button vypocti;
EditText vstup;
TextView vysledek;
TextView vypocetjavy;
TextView vypocetndk;
BigInteger faktorial = BigInteger.valueOf(1);



static {  
    System.loadLibrary("kru13_ndktest_NDKTestActivity");  
}  


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    vstup = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    vysledek = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    vypocetjavy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    vypocetndk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    vypocti = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    vypocti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Button pressed.");

            Date zacatek = new Date();
            //Start Java calculating
            if (vstup.getText().toString().equals("")) vstup.setText("0");
            int num = Integer.parseInt(vstup.getText().toString());
            faktorial = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
            for(int i = 1; i<=num; i++){
                faktorial = faktorial.multiply(new BigInteger(i + ""));
            }
            vysledek.setText("");
            vysledek.setText("Result is: "+faktorial);
            Date konec = new Date();
            long rozdil = 0;
            rozdil = (konec).getTime() - zacatek.getTime();
            vypocetjavy.setText("");
            vypocetjavy.setText("Time with Java: "+rozdil+"ms.");
            //End Java calculating

            //Start NDK calculating
            Date zacatek2 = new Date();
            num = Integer.parseInt(vstup.getText().toString());
            helloLog(num);
            System.out.println(num);
            Date konec2 = new Date();
            long rozdil2 = 0;
            rozdil2 = (konec2).getTime() - zacatek2.getTime();
            vypocetndk.setText("");
            vypocetndk.setText("Time with NDK: "+rozdil2+"ms.");
            //End NDK calculating
        }
    });       
}

public void onClick(View V) {
    System.out.println("Button pressed.");
}
}
```

I don't know where is the mistake or what I missed or something.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Without digging through your code, are you sure that's the wrong answer?  It suggests that granularity and other things may be dominating the measurement over the actual computational work.  Perhaps you can try making the problem take longer (use a larger input number) and running many trials, doing an average where you discard outliers (at least those on the high side).  Benchmarking is not trivial to get right, especially on a multitasking system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I try to calculate factorial for 30 000, in Java it takes 138811ms but in NDK only 2ms. I think it is wrong. If I upload somewhere my project, can someone try it? Maybe take a look at it? Maybe it is only mistake with calling NDK function, so if the function is not called correctly, it takes only 0-3ms to calculate factorial in NDK...

Comment: Am I missing something like this:                          NativeLibrary nativeobject = new NativeLibrary();
nativeobject.result(MainActivity.this);                               in my NDKTestActivity.java ? I found something like this in another Android NDK project

Comment: Having your code provide its answer for the calculation seems like an obvious check if it is doing the job or not.

Comment: I uploaded my project here: [link](http://ulozto.net/xGAwFX6z/myproject-zip) . I am desperate with that, where is the mistake, or what I am missing. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think I found that the problem is in NDKTest.cpp where is          jlong   faktorial = 1;
        jlong i;
        for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
            faktorial = faktorial * i;
        }                                                                 But when n=1000 for example, jlong is too small for faktorial. Is there any way for bigger numbers than in jlong date type?

Answer (score 0):

this behaviour is totally explainable for your code. you have a few mistakes. As you may know 30k! is a really big number.

- NDK:

  - you are using a single loop, doing 30k multiplications - this happens very fast indeed
  - you are using jlong (a limited 64 bit signed int) after about 20! it will overflow so your results are of course wrong
- Android:

  - BigInteger allocates memory in order to store your infinite number. each operation is increasingly difficult, the multiplication operation becoming increasingly complex
  - you have prints in the loop (or worse, SetText() on the UI!) - never include them in your measurements, they take time

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I removed prints and SetText() in Android part to accurate the measures. But can you help me please how to edit Native code in NDKTest.cpp to avoid overflow of jlong? What date type or something should I use?

Comment: Or maybe do this calculations in for cycle for example 1000 times for smaller number, for example 10, to generate difference in times between Java and NDK calculations?

Comment: there is no standard implementation of BigInteger in C/C++. You can search for various projects on the internet. https://gmplib.org/ seems to be actively updated. I wouldn't recommend repeating small iterations because Java will only get slow once you get to high numbers. but of course is perfectly fine if you don't actually need factorial of large numbers (which has an almost infinitely large result). if your purpose is actually not calculating large factorials and just a comparative benchmark between Java and C on android you could write some other code such as operations on strings etc.